# How can I put text over a fixed image in html and make the text scrollable?

Tags: html, css, css-position

This may be a stupid question, but I am making a website and I want to have a page that has a fixed image that stays where it is when you scroll to see more text. One problem that I have encountered is that I can get the image to be fixed, but then I cannot make other text scrollable. The other problem is that I can get the text to be scrollable but the text goes under the fixed image. Is there any way that I can fix this. I have been using very simple html divs with classes from a style.css file.

Comment: Learn about [z-index](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_pos_z-index.asp#:~:text=CSS%20z-index%20Property%201%20Definition%20and%20Usage.%20The,property%20to%20its%20default%20value.%205%20Related%20Pages)

Comment: What have you tried? Post the code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Geeky Quentin said, z-index is the solution to your problems. You mentioned that you are using classes in css, so in the class you should put z-index: index. The higher the index, the more things it goes over. If you want an image to stay where it is and not get anything put over or under it, you can just use different z-index indexes. If you separate the s then you should be able to make the text scrollable. I hope this answers your question.